# how can I authenticate with woo trade python helper

Tags: python

I am using the woo trade python api. I cannot get past the authentication stage. Here is the code:

```
from wootrade import Client


    API = 'my_api_key'
    SECRET = 'my_api_secret'
    APPLICATION_ID = 'my_app_id'
    
    client = Client(API, APPLICATION_ID, SECRET, testnet=True)
    info = client.get_account_info()
    print(info)
```

The error message is:

```
[ERROR] Request failed!
APIError(code=-1002): invalid api key.
None
```

I am sure that the api_key, api_secret and application id are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change arguments order as follows. API Secret has to come before App ID:

```
Client(API, SECRET, APPLICATION_ID, testnet=True)
```

Also, [official guidance](https://github.com/wanth1997/python-wootrade) suggests to use os.getenv() to wrap arguments. Try it, if you still encounter an error.

```
import os

API = os.getenv("API")
SECRET = os.getenv("SECRET")
APPLICATION_ID = os.getenv("APPLICATION_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message.
I found the solution:

```
testnet=False
```